# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. when I composer update

Tags: laravel

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install botman/tinker 1.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install botman/tinker 1.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install botman/tinker 1.0.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install botman/tinker 1.0.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install botman/tinker 1.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install botman/tinker 1.2.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires botman/tinker ~1.0 -> satisfiable by botman/tinker[1.0.0, ..., 1.2.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.0.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.0.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.2.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.3.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.4.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.5.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.6.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.7.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.7.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.8.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.9.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.10.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.11.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.11.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.11.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.12.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.12.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.12.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.12.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.13.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.14.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.15.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.16.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.16.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.17.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.17.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.17.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.18.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.18.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.19.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.20.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.20.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.21.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.22.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.22.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.23.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.23.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.24.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.25.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.26.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.26.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.27.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.28.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.28.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.29.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.30.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.30.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.31.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.32.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.32.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.33.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.33.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.34.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.35.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.35.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.36.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.36.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.36.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.37.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.38.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.39.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.40.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.0.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - botman/tinker 1.0.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev].
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev], laravel/framework[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

`composer.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "botman/studio",
  "description": "BotMan Chatbot framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "botman",
    "chatbot",
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.4",
    "botman/botman": "~2.0",
    "botman/driver-telegram": "^1.6",
    "botman/driver-web": "~1.0",
    "botman/studio-addons": "~1.3",
    "botman/tinker": "~1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.3",
    "jaeger/querylist": "^4.2",
    "laravel/helpers": "^1.4",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
},
  "require-dev": {
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
        ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "BotMan\\Studio\\Providers\\DriverServiceProvider::publishDriverConfigurations"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "BotMan\\Studio\\Providers\\DriverServiceProvider::publishDriverConfigurations"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: It means that botman/tinker is not compatible with your updated laravel version. The package was last updated 7 months ago.

Comment: The latest version of botman/tinker appears to work on Laravel 7 or lower.